# Is there any specific word to describe this selfish idea?

Tags: word-usage

"I support using cleaner energy source in moral, but if it harm my profit,eg:pay extra fee, I would not support"

Is there any specific term to describe such idea?

Comment: Selfishness....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd describe that person as [opportunistic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/opportunistic):

> - Taking immediate advantage, often unethically, of any circumstance of possible benefit.

The following saying also comes to mind:

[Practice what you preach](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/practice+what+you+preach):

> - Prov. Cliché You yourself should do the things you advise other people to do. *Dad always told us we should only watch an hour of television every day, but we all knew he didn't practice what he preached.*

The Free Dictionary